# Python Error: time data does not match format

Tags: python, pandas

I was using a CSV and took out a few dates then resaved it and suddenly my code that worked before did not work anymore. I tried referencing the old CSV and got the same error despite it running fine before.
Here is what I had tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
Q = pd.read_csv("Data_V3.csv")
Q['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Q['date'], format='%m-%d-%Y')
```

The CVS looks like this:

```
date:     flow:
1/1/1930  1300
```

I also tried:

```
Q['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Q['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

The full error is: "ValueError: time data '1/1/1930' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y' (match)"

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `/` instead of `-` in your code to match the format.

```
Q['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Q['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

When you read the error, it gives you some information you probably skip over when you read it:

"ValueError: time data **'1/1/1930'** does not match format **'%m-%d-%Y'** (match)"

That is an exact example of what broke your code. Then it gives you the format as well. The only difference that breaks it is a `/` from the example given.

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you try to change you're .csv into :

```
date:     flow:
01/01/1930  1300
```

Comment: Python does ask for zero-padded numbers but non-zero padded works fine as well.

Comment: I just updated my CSV to be padded with a 0 in front to be "01/01/1930" for example, but my code is still not working.